# How to invoke/call a sequence inside a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I want to auto-increment the table id I have created. This table will save logs about changes made from a certain table in my database. Below is my code and the error I'm getting. Please help me and thank you in advance.

```
create or replace Trigger PVFC_audit
after insert or delete or update on customer
for each row 
declare
v_user varchar2(20);
eventlog_id_go number;
v_date date;
v_time timestamp;
act_done varchar2(20) := case when updating then 'Update' when deleting then 'Delete' else 'Insert' end;
begin
IF eventlog_id IS NULL THEN  <--- eventlog_id is the actual column in my eventlogs table
SELECT eventlog_id_seq.NEXTVAL , user, To_Char(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYY'), To_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'HH12:MI:SS')
INTO eventlog_id_go, v_user, v_date, v_time from dual;
END IF;
if inserting then
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (eventlog_id_go, v_user, v_date, v_time, act_done , 'customer');
elsif deleting then
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (eventlog_id_go, v_user, v_date, v_time, act_done,'customer');
elsif updating then
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (eventlog_id_go, v_user, v_date, v_time, act_done ,'customer');
end if;
end;
```

-----Below is the sequence I've created-----

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "SYSTEM"."EVENTLOG_ID_SEQ"  
MINVALUE 1 
MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1 
CACHE 20 
NOORDER  
NOCYCLE ;
```

Error(13,4): PLS-00201: identifier 'EVENTLOG_ID' must be declared

Comment: Is eventlog_id is column from customer table? If not than what is it?

Comment: eventlog_id is a column from another table named eventlogs. this table will accept reports of operations done on the customer table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> eventlog_id is a column from another table named eventlogs

So you can't reference it in a trigger: a trigger only sees the columns of the table which owns it. The solution is just populate the `eventlog_id` column in the INSERT statement.

Incidentally your trigger has a lot of duplication. You can simplify immensely:

```
create or replace Trigger PVFC_audit
after insert or delete or update on customer
for each row 
declare
    act_done varchar2(20) := case when updating then 'Update' when deleting then 'Delete' else 'Insert' end;
begin

    if inserting then
        act_done := 'INSERT';
    elsif deleting then
        act_done := 'DELETE';
    elsif updating then
        act_done := 'UPDATE';
    end if;
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (eventlog_id_seq.NEXTVAL , user, To_Char(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYY'), To_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'HH12:MI:SS')
    , act_done ,'customer');

end;
```

Not sure why you're populating `date_done` and`time_done` as strings. It would make way more sense to use the correct data types.

```
    insert into eventlogs(eventlog_id, user_name, date_done, time_done, action_done, object_name)
    values (eventlog_id_seq.NEXTVAL , user, trunc(sysdate), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    , act_done ,'customer');
```

If EVENTLOGS has those columns defined as VARCHAR2 then that is almost definitely a data model bug which will give you grief at some point.

Comment: just one thing: is says invalid month. But, manage to fix it. Thank you @APC.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to reference [pseudorecords](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955) old/new value

```
IF :OLD.eventlog_id IS NULL THEN
```

or

```
IF :NEW.eventlog_id IS NULL THEN
```

Comment: The same error: Error(13,4): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.EVENTLOG_ID'      ----- Error(13,4): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.EVENTLOG_ID'

Comment: you are missing colon? :NEW

Comment: @APC - Sir I've coded it correctly, yet the same error. Colon is not shown in the error report. here's my code - IF :OLD.eventlog_id IS NULL THEN 
SELECT eventlog_id_seq.NEXTVAL , user, To_Char(sysdate,'DD/MON/YYY'), To_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'HH12:MI:SS')
INTO eventlog_id_go, v_user, v_date, v_time from dual;
END IF;

Comment: Is eventlog_id is column from customer table? If not than what is it?

Comment: eventlog_id is a column from another table named eventlogs. this table will accept reports of operations done on the customer table.

Comment: If it's not connected with customer table than you should not check it. I assume you will always need new id.

Comment: I erased the checking just now. I now have different problems showing up respectively. --- eventlog_id is a column from another table named eventlogs. this table will accept reports of operations done on the customer table. ---- SEVERE 436 323394 oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$1 null at (Internal error) No Throwable Stack Element ---- SEVERE 425 0 oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$1 208 at oracle.dbtools.parser.Matrix.get(Matrix.java:28) ---- Now I'm in a real trouble.